# Textbox name cannot start with a number in SSRS2008?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working with **SSRS 2008** in some existing reports I have. One of the new requirements is to add a few columns and two of them begins with a number in its header. For example: **170T_Test**.

When displaying the data and headers in the Report Viewer all is OK.

HOWEVER, the problem is when exporting to **CSV format**. Since the headers showed in this format are taken from the textbox property name, I had to put 170T_Test as the name. But, trying to do that the SSRSS 2008 IDE shows the following messages error:

> "Specify a valid name. The name cannot contain spaces, and it must
>   begin with a letter followed by letter, numbers, or the undescore
>   character (_)"

So, based on all the explained above, is there a way to have the textbox starting with a number? or is it prohibited?

Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved in two different ways.

I prefer method 1. It is much better and reuseable.

**Method 1:** 
***Step 1***
Update your report dataset to include the headers on row 1.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT Field1, Field2, 2 as rowOrder
  FROM Tables
  Where Conditions
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '170T Test' AS Field1, '180 T$' AS Field2, 1 as rowOrder
) ORDER BY rowOrder
```

***Step 2:*** 
Modify the `RSReportServer.config` file on Report server to customize CSV export to *exclude header*.

2012 config file Location: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer`

2008 File Location: `\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\Reporting Services\ReportServer`

**Imp:** Make a backup of the `RSReportServer.config` in case you need to rollback your changes.

Add another entry in `<render>` section below CSV extension.

```
<Extension name="CSVNoHeader" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
    <OverrideNames>
        <Name Language="en-US">CSV No Header</Name>
    </OverrideNames>
    <Configuration>
        <DeviceInfo>
            <NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
        </DeviceInfo>
     </Configuration>
</Extension>
```

Save it. Now you have another drop down export option *CSV No Header* along with CSV, PDF, XML. Users can use this option to extract the data the way they want.

[MSDN Link to customize Rendering extension](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx)

**Method 2:**
***STEP 1***
Same as above

***STEP 2***
Use URL access and specify the device info for no header
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155046.aspx

Comment: Hi Anup. Thanks for your help. The solution you posted is a valid one too. Indeed in some other reportrs we have used that approach

Answer (score 1):

Resources can't start with a number or a reserved word, if you do this, visual studio will automaticly add an underscore '_' in front of your name.
Your problem probably has something to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wanted to make sure that it works in that way. I will let the user know about this limitation