# how to change headers while exporting to csv in .rdl (SSRS) file in visual studio?

Tags: csv, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I'm working with .rdl(SSRS) file in visual studio and when i run it on browser the headers are as belows :

[image]

But when i export it to csv the headers are coming as the column names of the table in sql as below :
[image]

How to change the column name to the one displaying at the browser(image 1) while exporting to csv. Please help!

Comment: how have you defined the colors? are they like "Black" or "Orange" ?

Comment: colors is not the issue. The header names are coming as the sql column name when exporting to csv

Comment: Are you exporting it in Excel(.xls) or CSV format? This is the issue you usually get when exporting in CSV not in excel.

Comment: @rohitsingh You can use this method to get header name as you want.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637444/textbox-name-cannot-start-with-a-number-in-ssrs2008/22642483#22642483

Comment: i'm exporting to csv

Comment: @rohitsingh Did you try the above solution. Did it work for you? Do you have any questions.